# Rendering partials for Sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partials

Does the render partial function take any type of collection? I tried passing a Set (@dogs) in and it doesn't seem to work:

```
<%= render(:partial => "dog", :collection => @dogs, :as => :dog) %>
```

I tried looking it up on the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html but it doesn't seem to suggest any limitation on sets... Is there something I have missed or another way to find out?

Thanks.

PS But when I tried to convert the very set to an array and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with a set, because the [`PartialRenderer#collection`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb#L318) method attempts to coerce the collection to an array using `to_ary`:

```
def collection
  if @options.key?(:collection)
    collection = @options[:collection]
    collection.respond_to?(:to_ary) ? collection.to_ary : []
  end
end
```

However `Set`s do not implement `to_ary`, so, as you have found, you must pass the collection like this:

```
:collection => @dogs.to_a
```

Comment: would you say basically dont use sets as most ruby code only knows how to deal with hash/array?

Answer (score -1):

The proper way is to pass collection to a partials is

`<%= render partial: "cat", locals: {cats: @cats} %>`

Comment: That is the correct way to pass a whole collection to a partial. However, `render partial: "cat", collection: @cats` renders the partial once for each object in the collection, which is a whole different thing.